# Embed a YouTube video in HTML5 without Flash

Tags: video, html, youtube

Is it possible to embed a YouTube video on your own website using HTML5, so it can be played on Safari on iPhone without Flash?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID"></iframe>
```

That will play in HTML5 video (falling back on Flash when HTML5 video is unavailable).

Comment: The actual behavior is to play in flash if both flash and html5 are available, and html5 only if flash is not available. You can try adding the html5=1 parameter to the query string to force html5 when both flash and html5 are available, but people report mixed results.

Comment: for some reason I am unable to center the youtube iframe using marin-left/right: auto; like I can with other elements. And using the <object> embed method doesn't seem to work on iPhone.