# Playing an embedded YouTube video with or without Flash, with or without Javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, youtube

Using the new YouTube embed code videos play without Flash. However, with Javascript disabled the videos no longer play.

What I would like is an elegant way to embed YouTube videos that covers all bases:

- Javascript on, with Flash
- Javascript on, no Flash
- No Javascript, with Flash
- No Javascript, no Flash

Currently, my best result comes from using the new embed code for those with Javascript, the old embed code for those without. This does not cover those without Javascript or Flash.

Is there a simpler solution, or am I on the right track?

See: http://carolineelisa.com/rkl/video_TITTB.html

The code snippet (the iframe is hidden from those without Javascript):

```
<iframe id="js-only" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/z73ZKb50V3Y?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<noscript>
<object width="640" height="390">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/z73ZKb50V3Y?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US">
  </param>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
  </param>
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
  </param>
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/z73ZKb50V3Y?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="390" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
</noscript>
```

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly is the `<iframe>` hidden for those without JavaScript?

Comment: Hey @Pointy. I hide the iframe by default using CSS (`#js-only {
 display:none;
}`, then, add a class of `video` to the page using jQuery (`$(function(){$('html').addClass('video');});`, then show iframe (`.video #js-only {
 display:block;
}`.

Comment: Oh OK.  Thanks; I was just curious. I wish I could help with an answer but this stuff is outside my area of experience. When I load the page in Chrome (with Flash installed and enabled), it seems to pick the Flash version over the HTML5 version, for whatever that's worth.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it myself but [the "Video for Everybody!"](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) solution might work for you.

It starts by attempting to embed the video using HTML5 video but if that fails then it tries Flash. Finally, if Flash fails then it provides a link to the video so hypothetically the user could just view it in their browser using Quicktime, VLC, whatever.

> "...automatically without the use of JavaScript or browser-sniffing."

Comment: Thanks @Mike C, I will take a look.  For now the client seems happy with my makeshift solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Q&A

[Embed a YouTube video in HTML5 without Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919856/embed-a-youtube-video-in-html5-without-flash)

@Delan Azabani already answered

According to http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html

You can use code like this

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Replace your **VIDEO_ID**

Comment: Thanks thegodth, I am using that code already. See the first line of my code above. It was a while ago now, but I believe the problem was that it wasn't working for those without javascript, that is why I used another snippet within a `<noscript>` tag below it.